# UINavigationController in Storyboard with custom UIToolbar xib fails

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm trying to load a simple custom xib for a UIToolbar with a single label just to get things working and in my `init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)` method fails while trying to modify the text of the label because it's not yet instantiated.

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

**I am using a UIView in place of a UIToolbar** here because it is easier to work with and this could be the problem. If I use a UIToolbar in my xib document, it forces everything I place onto the UIToolbar to be a UIBarButtonItem and the unfortunate size-effect of this is the undesired padding this creates. Note the red bar tint that can be seen when adding UIViews to a UIToolbar in the image here (look at how ugly the red is! ):

[image: UIToolbar with red bar tint]

I believe that I have set all of the necessary settings and IBOutlets in the Inspector panel of Xcode. And with simple centred x,y layout constraints.

**Update 1:**

If I add a UIView to a UIToolbar, I will be stuck with a view hierarchy of UIToolbar > UIBarButtonItem > UIView. With the UIView selected and reading the Size Inspector on the right panel of Xcode, you will see something similar to the following:

[image]

This has the unfortunate side-effect of an unusable set of points (16 to the left of the UIView and 6 on top). Albeit, with a sufficiently large UIView, the 6 points on top can be regained however the 16 to the left cannot. Again, note the red margin in the top image.

**Update 2:**

Any UIView offset of 16 points is now fixed with my new solution below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found your Problem.

Your Problems, **you took UIView in .XIB in place of UIToolbar**.

follow below Steps.

1) You need to delete **UIView** from **XIB** file . and **add UIToolbar** in place of UIVIew.

[image]

2) Assign Identity to XIB **CustomToolbar.swift**

[image]

3) Now set **IBOutlet** to Item in your **CustomToolbar.swift**

[image]

4) In your Viewdidload put below code,

```
let toolBar = UINib(nibName: "CustomToolbar", bundle: nil).instantiateWithOwner(nil, options: nil).first as! CustomToolbar

        self.navigationController!.view.addSubview(toolBar)
        self.navigationController!.toolbarItems = toolBar.items
```

5) In your All viewcontrollers viewdidload add

```
self.toolbarItems = self.navigationController!.toolbarItems
```

**Edit:-** You can Add UIView in UIToolbar And add controll according to your Requirement.

[image]

I hope this info will helpful to you.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I understand that my UIView is very well problem #1. I'm not interested in adding buttons to the UIToolbar but I want to customize the toolbar as I would like any other UIView...

Comment: You can see in my question that I have already attempted adding a UIToolbar to my xib but it has side effects of having padding around the button. I want to have the view encapsulate the whole space.

Comment: check Edited Answer.

Comment: and One More thing You said UIToolbar so , i give answer with UIToolbar. If you want UIView in All controller then you can just take Normal .XIB with UIView. and Just addSubview as XIB in All the view controller.

Comment: Do you know of a way to set the X and Y coordinates of a UIView on a UIToolbar? The size inspector locks X = 16 and Y = 6... My goal is to reach the edges of the UIToolbar view. I will update my question with this.

Comment: I am not sure but it is not possible. to start it from 0

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104505/discussion-between-badal-shah-and-alex-smith).

Comment: @AlexSmith what is your problem buddy. sometime you doing right or sometime wrong. ?

Answer (score 2):

Your xib reference missing. That's why you got fatal error.

While debug, you will get 'UILabel' is nil.

Without using .xib, you can use my following code.

```
    import Foundation
    import UIKit

    class CustomToolbar: UIToolbar {
       var label: UILabel!

        required convenience init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
            self.init(aDecoder)
            self.initialize()
        }

        init(_ coder: NSCoder? = nil) {
            if let coder = coder {
                super.init(coder: coder)!
            }
            else {
                super.init(frame: CGRectZero)
            }
        }

        // Initial the toolbar based on the frame.
        override init(frame:CGRect) {
            super.init(frame:frame)
            self.initialize()
        }

        // Initialize the label.
        func initialize() {
            self.label = UILabel.init();
            self.label.textColor = UIColor.redColor();
            self.label.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(18);
            self.label.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width, 21);
            self.addSubview(self.label);
            label.text = "Some text assigned programmatically" // Success
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, yes. Without a xib, your code works! But I really wanted to use a xib.

Answer (score 0):

@BadalShah is correct though his implementation of handling adding a subview in either a UINavigationController subclass or a UIViewController is not quite desirable - it should be handled within the CustomToolbar class as outlined here.

@VigneshKumar is almost correct! I needed to load the nib inside my CustomToolbar class. Before, I had applied the CustomToolbar class name to a UIView which was wrong. I needed only assign it to the File's Owner. Giving the xib a different filename from that of my custom class helped too in that I became less confused of what view needed what class name assignment.

```
let nibName = "MyView"

func setup() {
    view = loadViewFromNib()
    view.frame = bounds
    view.autoresizingMask = [.FlexibleWidth, .FlexibleHeight]
    addSubview(view)
}

func loadViewFromNib() -> UIView {
    let bundle = NSBundle(forClass: self.dynamicType)
    let nib = UINib(nibName: nibName, bundle: bundle)
    let view = nib.instantiateWithOwner(self, options: nil).first as! UIView
    return view
}

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setup()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    setup()

    // label should already be initialized. Let's try changing the text!
    label.text = "Some new data!" // Works! 
}
```